# Texture with D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET failing to release before IDirect3DDevice9::Reset

Tags: directx9

Creating the texture:

```
IDirect3DSurface9 *bbsurf;

if (SUCCEEDED (Device->GetRenderTarget (0, &bbsurf)))
{
    D3DSURFACE_DESC desc;

    if (SUCCEEDED (bbsurf->GetDesc (&desc)))
    {
        Device->CreateTexture (
            desc.Width,
            desc.Height,
            1,
            D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET,
            desc.Format,
            D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
            &GAndCRT,
            NULL);
    }

    // don't leak
    SAFE_RELEASE (bbsurf);
}
```

Before Resetting the device:

```
GAndCRT->Release ();
GAndCRT = NULL;
```

I've commented out all other code that refers to this texture but the texture still fails to Release and the device Reset fails.  To be clear: the above *is* the minimum complete example to reproduce the problem.

Commenting out the CreateTexture call and obviously the device will succeeed to Reset.

There are about 4 other textures also created with D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET which Release OK.

I know there's no magical incantation that will say "please *really* Release this texture, so what I'm looking for is information and/or advice on how to best go about troubleshooting this further, rather than an actual answer.

Comment: Manually managing COM reference's is a pain, so a better solution in C++ is to use a smart pointer like ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` (see [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr)) which is part of the Windows 8.x/10 SDK. Also, not sure why you are using a 12+ year old legacy version of Direct3D instead of say Direct3D 11 here.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn - not my choice, a customer requirement, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The code for creating the texture was being called twice during system startup owing to an unitialized BOOL flagging whether the D3D device was lost.